# nginx with oauth

Tags: oauth, nginx

I'll try to explain our problem:
We have a application based on Apache web server.
But not long time ago there was a task to remove apache and make everything work on nginx. 
We try to installed nginx and test our application.
In addition we have added nginx rewrite engine for our site to load.
But we have a problem of implementing OAuth to work in nginx.
Error message: "The PHP OAuth Extension is not installed"

Does anyone encountered similar problem?

I have searched and have not found out the solutions. I have found links to:
http oauth engine that was writen long ago https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_http_oauth_module . I myself do not know how to integrate it, besides its experimental and i do not know will it work for sure.

If someone have encountered similar problem and solved it, please help us.

Comment: You want the PHP OAuth module, not the Nginx OAuth module.

Comment: Nginx, cause everything worked on apache.

Comment: I'm not asking you, I'm telling you :) Your error message indicates that your PHP does not see an installed OAuth module. Chances are that your Apache setup used `mod_php` while your Nginx setup likely uses FastCGI PHP; those often have separate configuration files, and the PHP OAuth module might not get loaded in your new FastCGI environment.

Comment: Apache may have been loading OAuth for you (through an apache php extension directive). Try finding the .so extension and adding this into your php.ini directly.

Comment: We have added extension=oauth.so to our php.ini file, 
restarted nginx service, but it did not helped.

Comment: THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED!

Thank you, everyone. The problem was that we did not restarted php-frm service. When we manualy restarted it "/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart" the error message was gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have rep enough to comment so I'm quoting the solution since it's on the comments and can be missed easily.

> THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED! Thank you, everyone. The problem was that we did not restarted php-frm service. When we manualy restarted it "/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart" the error message was gone. –  user1448914 Jun 11 '12 at 13:31

So if you are in the same situation as OP and me, this fixed it:

`service php5-fpm restart`

Comment: Also worked here, I saw the module was recognized by php by typing `php -m`. I wanted to test it and opened phpinfo() where there was still no section called Oauth, even after a Nginx restart. since `service` is not recognized here `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart` solved the issue.